# Login Script using InputField

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class HSController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string addScoreURL = "IP ADDRESS/adduser.php"; //be sure to add a ? to your url


    void Start()
    {
        //string scores = nameField.text;


        StartCoroutine (PostScores (scores));
    }

    // remember to use StartCoroutine when calling this function!
    IEnumerator PostScores(string name)//string name)
    {


        //This connects to a server side php script that will add the name and score to a MySQL DB.
        // Supply it with a string representing the players name and the players score.

        // first we create a new WWWForm, that means a "post" command goes out to our database (for futher information just google "post" and "get" commands for html/php
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

        // with this line we will give a new name and save our score into that name
        // those "" indicate a string and attach the score after the comma to it
        form.AddField("NAME", name);


        // the next line will start our php file that saves the Score and attaches the saved values from the "form" to it
        // For this tutorial I've used a new variable "db_url" that stores the path
        WWW webRequest = new WWW(addScoreURL, form);

        // with this line we'll wait until we get an info back
        yield return webRequest;
    }



}
```

but i want to get the users name that they have entered into an inputField. But i can't figure it out. I have the input field and a submit button on the scene but how do i connect them to my script and pass it to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1st. Remove your PHP Tag. I know it is something to do with PHP. Since it is a post Request but non Unity3D. Developers may waste their time looking at your question.

```
// Make this public so it will be available in the inspector. Check what game object is attached to

// Drag the Text into the MyInputField.

public Text MyInputField;

form.AddField(MyInputField.text, myinput);

// If you don't like Dragging it from the Inspector or don't want your Myinputfield to be public

// You can use GameObject.Find("MYinputFieldName").GetComponent<Text>();

// GameObject.Find is Slow and should be avoided if you're Performance concious.
```